# find the numbers that are NOT most frequent from a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, frequency

I would like to find the numbers that are not most frequent from a matrix for every column in matlab

for eg..,

```
 a = [3 3 1 4; 0 0 1 1; 0 1 2 4]
```

The answer I expect is

```
[3 3 2 1]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Raja

Comment: How do you want to choose in the case of a tie (e.g. column 2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that in case of a `tie` for the minimum count in a column, you would settle for the minimum valued element, this is a **[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** based solution code to solve it -

```
%%// Unique values across the entire matrix
unqval = unique(a(:))

%// Counts of those unique values for each column
counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq,a,permute(unqval,[3 2 1])),1)

%// Make the zero counts as NaNs as they don't exist at all for a column
counts(counts==0)=NaN

%// Indices for the minimum counts with the minimum valued element in a tie-case
[~,v2] = nanmin(permute(counts,[3 2 1]))

%// Minimum count elements of input for each coloumn, to form the desired output
out = unqval(v2).'
```

---

Alternative approach using `for-loop` -

```
alf(1,size(a,2))=0; %// alf would be the desired output
for k = 1:size(a,2)
    unqval = unique(a(:,k));
    [~,ind] = min(histc(a(:,k),unqval));
    alf(k) = unqval(ind);
end
```

Comment: Dear @Divakar, Thanks for your idea. It works fine for small matrix, but for large matrices 'bsxfun' takes lots of time and my matlab got stuck. So any suggestions please.

Comment: @user8162 Yeah this is basically a brute-force and memory-hungry approach for your problem.

Comment: @user8162 Check out the new approach and see if it performs any better for your case!

Answer (score 1):

This gives the lowest value in case of a tie:

```
u = unique(a(:)).'; %'// find unique values of a
h = histc(a, u); %// count for each value, in each column
h(h==0) = inf; %// mark non-present values
[~, r] = min(h); %// find first (i.e. lowest) value with minimum count
result = u(r); %// build result
```

Comment: This is what I was missing `histc(a, u)` as I thought `histc` works only with vectors, but apparently matrices work too huh!! This one has to be OP's choice! +1 of course.

Comment: Also `unique + histc` is so widely used in various applications, Mathworks guys might think about making a separate function combining these! :)

Comment: Hi Luis., My matrix is of 513x1400. So histc is taking lots of time. S o any other suggestion which makes it fast? Thanks..

Comment: @Divakar I agree! Another thing I miss is `accumarray` with a matrix as second argument :-)

Comment: @user8162 If it's a memory issue (are you experiencing [disk thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science))?), use @Divakar's `for` loop approach (+1 from me), which works with one column at a time and thus may be more memory-efficient. If memory is not an issue, it may be hard to speed this up